# Generalization of de Rham cohomology, or cohomology for non-smooth case

Tags: homology-cohomology, divergence-operator

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a contractible region and $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a vector field on $f$. If $f$ is smooth vector field and $\nabla\cdot f=0$, then $f=\nabla\times g$ for some smooth vector field $g:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ by de Rham's theorem. ($\because H_{dR}^{2}(\Omega)=H^{2}(\Omega)=0$)

But recently, I heard that this result does not holds for **non-smooth** vector fields in general. In 2007, theorem 4.1 of [this paper](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/213/art%253A10.1007%252Fs00526-007-0094-9.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%2Fs00526-007-0094-9&token2=exp=1469496429~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F213%2Fart%25253A10.1007%25252Fs00526-007-0094-9.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1007%252Fs00526-007-0094-9*~hmac=cf3bb24ed198d60349715f04d20a6b0283adb30da28fc286e6450ad3d631a34d) shows that if $\Omega$ is contractible region in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $f$ is vector field on $\Omega$ with $\nabla\cdot f=0$ (here $f$ is not necessarily smooth). Then if $f$ is $L^{1}$, there exists (unique) $g\in L^{3/2}(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^{3})$ s.t. $f=\nabla\times g$.

Actually, I have 2 questions :

> 1) Is there any non-smooth vector field on simply-connected domain s.t. $\nabla\cdot f=0$ but $f=\nabla\times g$ does not have a solution?
>
> 2) Is there any cohomology theory that considers non-smooth vector fields? (for example, $C^{k}$ vector fields for some $k\geq 0$?)

Thanks!

Comment: For (2), the general problem is that $C^k$ is not closed under differentiation, so defining the corresponding (co)chain complex in terms of an exterior derivative is going to be difficult. You can weaken the smoothness condition as in singular cohomology, strengthen it as in $L^2$-cohomology, or work with another type of object as in sheaf cohomology. I'm not familiar with any specific kind of $C^k$ cohomology, probably for the reason mentioned above and the same sort of argument as to why we don't study $C^k$ (rather than just $C^0$ or smooth) manifolds.